# Laravel 9 with Docker - CSS and JS not loading using Vite

Tags: laravel, docker, vite

I'm having trouble in determining the cause of not `loading` of my `CSS stylesheet` and `Javascript` on my `Laravel 9` project using `Docker` in my Windows OS.
I have done all the steps after creating containers and no error message thrown in my page.
Should I run `npm run dev` in the container? I have no issue before using `mix` but I really need to deploy this project.

I also attached screenshot below from `chrome dev tools` that everything in my `app.js` & `app.css` is not loading

Dockerfile:

```
# Set master image
FROM php:8.0-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
git \
curl \
libpng-dev \
libonig-dev \
libxml2-dev \
zip \
unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

 #Laravel App
 app:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: dr3
  container_name: app
  volumes: 
   - .:/var/www/
  ports: 
   - "9000:9000"
  networks:
   - laraveldockerize

 #Nginx Service
 nginx:
  image: nginx:stable-alpine
  container_name: nginx
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
   - "8000:80"
  volumes: 
   - .:/var/www
   - ./dockerize/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  networks:
   - laraveldockerize

 #MySQL Service
 db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: db
  restart: unless-stopped
  tty: true
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  environment:
   MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
   # MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  volumes:
   - ./dockerize/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
   - ./dockerize/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql-custom.cnf
  networks:
   - laraveldockerize

 node:
  image: node:alpine
  container_name: node
  working_dir: /var/www/
  tty: true
  ports:
   - 5173:5173
  volumes:
   - ./:/var/www
  networks:
   - laraveldockerize

 #Docker Networks
 networks:
  laraveldockerize:
   driver: bridge
```

Vite:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1: I don't know what you using the 'node' container for. If you switched from mix to vite I assume you run vite inside the laravel container (app).
Looks for me that you can remove the 'node' container.

2: you have to open the vite port on your 'app' container:

```
 app:
  ports: 
   - "9000:9000"
   - "5173:5173"
```

Vite default port ist 5173.

3: you must run vite with --host option:

```
npm run dev --host
```

This did the trick for me and I'm using similar docker configuration with laravel, mysql & nginx.

If you don't want to type '--host' each time, you can adjust the script in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "vite build"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that problem by only running `npm run build` in the project folder and then continuing with `docker-composer up --build`.

After any change of styles, you need to reload the page.

It doesn't need to use a 'node' container.